# how to fill dropdown list from extra huge datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, performance, drop-down-menu

i have table from database this table has 400000 row in my asp page my dropdown list(ddlPlaintiffName) fill from
this method

```
 private void FillPlaintiff()
    {

        //declare connection by pass connection string from web.config
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection
            (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SystemConn"].ConnectionString);
        //declare sql statment  as astring variable

        SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand();
        sqlcom.Connection = sqlcon;
        sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcom.CommandText = "proc_SelectPlaintiff";



        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        //fill data set with data adabter that contain data from database
     //   sad.Fill(ds);
        sqlcon.Open();
         SqlDataAdapter sad = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcom);

         sad.Fill(ds);

        ddlPlaintiffName.DataSource = ds;
        ddlPlaintiffName.DataBind();
        ddlPlaintiffName.Items.Insert(0, "--select  --");
        sqlcon.Close();

    }
```

but every postback my load is very very slow how can i avoid this

Comment: I would suggest that you should _rethink_ your UI and instead of a dropdown have an auto-complete/search option. Even a few hunderd options is bad UI for a dropdown.

Comment: @Oded perfectly said-  this is totally not a technical Problem to start with, as a solution to this Problem (answer to this question) results in a non-functional UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you should not use such a big table for dropdown list. Since user can't find value easily , there is no use for him. You should provide some kind of search and based on search criteria, though ajax, data should show in dropdown list. Search should start only when user put three or more characters, Else your ajax based query also become slow.

Please refer the following page to get an idea

[jQuery Searchable DropDown Plugin Demo](http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Oded is the best option. I think that it have no sense a DropDownList like that.

In the other hand, the time issue is hard to avoid. You could use the `ViewState`, but 400,000 rows are like... too much! Maybe, if you explain what kind of data are you storing in this table we can think about an alternative way to do this

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the comments and answers that say "don't do this" are right - a drop down with more than a few dozen items is almost always useless to users.

Secondly, the answer to your question - if you can't change the user interface - is to introduce caching. There are several ways of doing this; which one you chose kinds depends on the specific bottleneck, but I'd start by reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).